# SimpleAdapter использованием собственного класса

Tags: java, android

Во всех примерах SimpleAdapter которые я нахожу (к примеру http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/simpleadapter.php ) создается хитрая конструкция типа ArrayList> myArrList;
Можно ли обойтись без нее, если у меня есть своя структура?

Как передать в SimpleAdapter свой массив, например Message[] msgs = new Message(5); ?

А может стоит создать класс от SimpleAdapter и изменить нужные функции?

Или вообще взять другой класс адаптера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам следует создать свой адаптер. В примере в адаптер передается массив с объектами `Product`

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<Product> objects;

    BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = products;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  // кол-во элементов
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
  }

  // элемент по позиции
  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
  }

  // id по позиции
  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  // пункт списка
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // используем созданные, но не используемые view
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
      view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    Product p = getProduct(position);

    // заполняем View в пункте списка данными из товаров: наименование, цена
    // и картинка
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

     return view;
 }

  // товар по позиции
  Product getProduct(int position) {
    return ((Product) getItem(position));
  }
```

[Источник](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: Спасибо @Athari , исправил